# SQL Server collecting SQL statements using particular index

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index

I'd like to capture SQL statements that uses a particular index. Is there a way I can utilize SQL Profiler or extended events to do so? I know I can view the plan cache to get a gist of the queries, but I'd like to capture the currently being executed queries real time.

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following query will find all the queries that are using that particular index at realtime

```
  select  i.object_id,
     i.index_id, i.name,
     tqp.query_plan,pl.plan_handle, pl.start_time,pl.estimated_completion_time,q.text
  from sys.indexes as i
    cross apply (select quotename(i.name) as name) as i2
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_requests as pl
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(pl.plan_handle) AS p
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(pl.plan_handle, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) tqp
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(pl.plan_handle) q
    where i.name = 'YourIndex'
```